# Yellow objects aspect on field of vision - THREE JS

Tags: javascript, object, colors, three.js

I've a problem with ThreeJS. I have a scene:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xf7d9aa, 100, 950);

var aspectRatio = GLOBAL.WIDTH / GLOBAL.HEIGHT;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    aspectRatio,
    0.1,
    1000
);

camera.position.z = 50;

scene.add(camera);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,

    antialias: true
});

renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);

renderer.setSize(GLOBAL.WIDTH, GLOBAL.HEIGHT);

renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

var container = $('.threejs-container');
container.append(renderer.domElement);

window.scene = scene;
```

and I have no lights but I still view my objects.
But, my objects in the "far" from the camera are yellow before taking their color.
Exemple, an objects with a z position at 900 is yellow but an object with z position at 100 is in the right color.

Here is an example with circles : https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9KOl.jpg

Can someone guides me?

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post your scene and an image of the issue?

Comment: Hi @meepzh! I edited my questio 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your fog is yellow!

```
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xf7d9aa, 100, 950);
```

You can see the color of `0xf7d9aa` here: http://hslpicker.com/#f7daab

If you don't want yellow, maybe you should change it to some form of grey. You could also increase the last value (`950`) so the fog isn't as strong at that distance.